# Can keepass 2 automatically log into website?

Tags: password-management, keepass, lastpass

Is there anyway Keepass 2 can act like Latpass and automatically log the user into a page visited which the username and password was stored for?

For example if Keepass was already opened and the database was loaded with a username/password to yahoo mail was present, when the user uses Firefox and navigates to the yahoo mail login page, could they be automatically logged in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keypass can't do this, but there are browser extensions such as [KeeFox](http://keefox.org/) that can.

Comment: I notice that keepass 1.26 has a 'perform autotype' option. does keefox do more than that?

Comment: With autotype you still need to open Keepass, select the entry you want and press the autotype button. Keefox selects the appropriate entry automatically, based on the URL you're at, and fills the login boxes. Of course, Keepass needs to be running an not be locked.

Comment: Oh, and what's more, Keefox completely overtakes Firefox's password saving functionality, allowing you to store passwords in Keepass directly.

Answer (score 0):

The global hotkey Ctrl+Alt+A while the cursor is in the username box will perform and auto-login, without having to navigate to KeePass and manually selecting the entry.  KeePass does have to be open for this to work, of course.